# Session Timeout using ActionFilter attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried to work on session timeout using Actionfilterattribute and onexecuting function in Filter config and called the attribute on top of all my controllers. After executing the application when session timed out nothing happens in the page. Instead, if I click something on my application it is redirecting me to the logout page. I need this to happen automatically. The page should refresh automatically and redirect to logout page if the session is expired.

My Filter Config code is as below:

```
public class SessionTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context.Session != null)
            {
                if (context.Session.IsNewSession)
                {
                    string sessionCookie = context.Request.Headers["Cookie"];

                    if (sessionCookie != null)
                    {

                        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                        string redirectTo = "";
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.RawUrl))
                        {

                            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
                            redirectTo = string.Format("~/Login/Logout", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.RawUrl));
                            //filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectTo);
                            return;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Web.config is also set as:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="2" />
```

someone please help me on this... What am I missing?

Comment: When you say you expect it to happen automatically do you mean that you request the page. Wait 15 minutes for your page to time out and then want the browser to redirect you to the login page? If so then you will need somethign clientside, not server side to do the redirect.

Comment: you can refresh your page with meta refresh tag or setTimeOut function on the client side.